# What should be the next move in this position?

Tags: analysis, strategy

```
 [FEN "2r1r1k1/pb5p/1pp1qb2/3p1p2/3Pn1p1/1Q2P1P1/PP2NPBP/2RRB1K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

What is the best move for Black in this position. Everything seems defended here. 
What method is applicable in such situations? Method of imbalances?

Comment: What's the method of imbalances?

Comment: It's Jeremy Silman's way of analyzing the game. Basically just find somewhere you can direct your play by looking at what's going on in the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All black pieces are currently defended but that does not mean there is nothing to do as if you play aimlessly white will eventually gain an advantage.

On analyzing the game the first thing you can notice is that the kingside is completely locked down by pawns so our attack needs to be on the queenside. Ba6 and Be7 are good moves to start gaining control on the queenside. Double rooks on c- file with a c5 pawn break is one option (but it sacrifices the d5 pawn).

Exploiting White's cramped position is essential for any strategy you employ on the queenside side. White will probably outpost his knight on the f4 square so BxN eventually will open up the e-file. Even though this is a drawish game it is far from over and inaccurate play from either player might lose the game.

Answer (score -2):

have to attack on the king side
advance krp  and also put horsie on kbishop 6 square for black
move rooks and q to kr file

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! This answer is hardly readable; please [edit] it to use algebraic notation and common names of chess pieces (i.e. not 'krp' or 'horsie').

Comment: krp= king rook pawn  ///   horsie is nickname for knight because the piece is a horsehead  ///  descriptive is more intuitive and easier to use ///   i see way too many kids who use algebraic but cant set up the board correctly unless they have some letters printed on it and on the correct side

Comment: I know, but 90% of the readers here doesn't. As it stands, the answer doesn't meet the minimum quality standards of the site and may be deleted.